# How can i loop through a consecutive window?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, regression

I have a df like this:

```
 > df
   symbol   x1      x2
1       A   3.6    5.2
2       A  10.0    4.8
3       A   5.2    0.2
4       A -10.2    0.4
5       A   5.4   -2.5
6       B   9.9    6.5
7       B  15.8   -1.8
8       B   4.5   -5.9
9       C  -2.0    0.5
10      C -10.0    2.6
11      C   7.7    8.9
12      C  10.5   18.5
```

I want to calculate the r squared between x1 and x2 column by symbol so I want to get a new df like this

```
  symbol r squared
1 A      0.27
2 B      0.30
3 C      0.68
```

I use ifelse but it isn't working.

```
for (i in 1:12){
            results[i] <- ifelse(df$symbol == symbollist[i], summary(lm(df$x1~df$x2))$r.squared,0)
           }
```

How can I solve this problem in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by`to perform `lm` for each symbol:

```
by(df, df$symbol, function(x) summary(lm(x1~x2, x))$r.squared)

df$symbol: A
[1] 0.07445258
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$symbol: B
[1] 0.09014209
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
df$symbol: C
[1] 0.687236
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` package for this. Try:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
              group_by(symbol) %>%
                  summarize(cor(x1, x2))
```